# Why do Repeated Go Windows builds result in different checksums?

Tags: go

When I build something with Go on my Mac, the binary has a consistent md5sum for repeated builds. However, when I cross compile for Windows, or build on Windows natively, I get a different checksum each time.

What is happening that causes this?

```
[kbrandt@glade: ~/] GOOS=windows go build
[kbrandt@glade: ~/] md5 -r tcollector.exe
f66dbec001eb0e02da261b4bc70d8072 tcollector.exe
[kbrandt@glade: ~/] GOOS=windows go build
[kbrandt@glade: ~/] md5 -r tcollector.exe
630e89fa4907b6811a3d19c99dbac2dc tcollector.exe
[kbrandt@glade: ~/] go build             
[kbrandt@glade: ~/] md5 -r tcollector    
0353160b4b000c7ba9d5331a72265291 tcollector
[kbrandt@glade: ~/] go build         
[kbrandt@glade: ~/] md5 -r tcollector
0353160b4b000c7ba9d5331a72265291 tcollector
```

Comment: There's probably a build timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

Windows PE files include a compilation timestamp, so this is expected - binaries compiled even one second apart will have a different timestamp embedded and thus a different hash.

Tools/procedures are available to ignore the timestamp field and other non-functional parts of the PE file so that binaries compiled at different times can be meaningfully compared. See, for example, this analysis of the TrueCrypt binaries: https://madiba.encs.concordia.ca/~x_decarn/truecrypt-binaries-analysis/

Answer (score 0):

Something in the output for windows depends on randomness or the time.

I don't know more than that (like what it is using that changes) **but it doesn't matter**

The output generated by compilers (even different versions of the same compiler) will vary and hashes are **designed** so similar things **don't** produce similar outputs.

A checksum is just that, something you can use to check you have the file and it is correct.

A bit of a null answer but there's no technical problem with what you are seeing happening.